# Softlayer API: Unable to apply objectFilter on Datacenters API

Tags: rest, filter, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to filter the API:
`https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters?objectFilter={"datacenters":{"name":{"operation":"ams01"}}}`

I am trying to filter the record for a DC: ams01.

Even after applying the above filter, all the records are getting returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters?objectFilter={"name":{"operation" : "ams01" }}
```

sometimes not need input the type when filtering primary datatypes.

Let me know if you have any problems/doubts.